# omnisharp with asp.net core 1.1 app

Tags: c#, vim, mono, .net-core, omnisharp

I'm trying to get code completion for a asp.net core 1.1 app in vi (neovim)

Here is the omnisharp server + vim plugin:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/Omnisharp-vim

In my .vimrc I added this:

```
Plug 'OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim'
let g:OmniSharp_server_type = 'roslyn'
```

(I think I need roslyn for .net core?)

I also cloned and compiled the omnisharp roslyn server without errors.
But when I start OmniSharp, I get this error:

```
/.local/share/nvim/plugged/omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-roslyn> ./artifacts/scripts/OmniSharp
OmniSharp:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys:GetUnixNamePrivate ()
  at Interop+Sys.GetUnixName () [0x00000] in <2c0705c248b844f597694acdb70b3a23>:0
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform (System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform osPlatform) [0x00009] in <2c0705c248b844f597694acdb70b3a23>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLogger..ctor (System.String name, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] filter, System.Boolean includeScopes) [0x00051] in <e9a418d09ae748d6a3f11d651b9e1106>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLoggerProvider.CreateLoggerImplementation (System.String name) [0x00019] in <e9a418d09ae748d6a3f11d651b9e1106>:0
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x00034] in <a33fd236349b4603bef9951b0ab37965>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLoggerProvider.CreateLogger (System.String name) [0x00000] in <e9a418d09ae748d6a3f11d651b9e1106>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.AddProvider (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider provider) [0x00000] in <6ac0afe55b53462283fd4e4f8f1658ac>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.AddProvider (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider provider) [0x00061] in <6ac0afe55b53462283fd4e4f8f1658ac>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleLoggerExtensions.AddConsole (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory factory, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] filter, System.Boolean includeScopes) [0x00008] in <e9a418d09ae748d6a3f11d651b9e1106>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleLoggerExtensions.AddConsole (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory factory, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] filter) [0x00000] in <e9a418d09ae748d6a3f11d651b9e1106>:0
  at OmniSharp.Startup.Configure (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder app, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, OmniSharp.Stdio.Services.ISharedTextWriter writer, OmniSharp.Services.IAssemblyLoader loader, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[TOptions] options) [0x00032] in <8853ad029e4d47c0b478044425f4b3a3>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <a33fd236349b4603bef9951b0ab37965>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <a33fd236349b4603bef9951b0ab37965>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder app) [0x00027] in <24af31b64ae843689736582353a19b3a>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder builder) [0x0000d] in <24af31b64ae843689736582353a19b3a>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication () [0x00080] in <24af31b64ae843689736582353a19b3a>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize () [0x00008] in <24af31b64ae843689736582353a19b3a>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build () [0x0008a] in <24af31b64ae843689736582353a19b3a>:0
  at OmniSharp.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Run>b__1 () [0x00196] in <8853ad029e4d47c0b478044425f4b3a3>:0
  at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute (System.String[] args) [0x0035b] in <e56ebbc3ed87488b8e26736bbadaa5d3>:0
  at OmniSharp.Program.Run (System.String[] args) [0x001ae] in <8853ad029e4d47c0b478044425f4b3a3>:0
  at OmniSharp.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0001c] in <8853ad029e4d47c0b478044425f4b3a3>:0
```

Here is some version information:

```
~> dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  af1e6684fd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.12
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.12-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4
~> mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 5.2.0.209 (2017-04/3d531ba Mon Jul  3 12:16:03 EDT 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c)
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
~>
```

Why do I even need Mono? Isn't dotnet core enough?
Does dotnet core only works with Roslyn?
What does vscode uses for c# completion? Roslyn?
What could be the problem here?

**UPDATE:**

I did a publish from the roslyn folder (~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-roslyn) like this: 'dotnet publish -c Release -f netcoreapp1.1'

Then I copied the files from the publish folder (~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-roslyn/artifacts/publish/OmniSharp/default/netcoreapp1.1) to the scripts folder (~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-roslyn/artifacts/scripts).

Not sure if this is the correct solution, but it seems to work.

**UPDATE 2:**

In the end I just downloaded a release from here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/releases

I then changed omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-roslyn/artifacts/scripts/OmniSharp to something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
"/<path>/omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-osx-x64-netcoreapp1.1/Omnisharp" "$@"
```

Now it works

Comment: "OmniSharp works both on Windows and on Linux and OS X with Mono." from the repository, so it doesn't states to be .net Core compatible, that's why you need mono, mono is a port of .net Classic, .net Core is extremely different inside. And the problem, that usually happens because you don't have published the code and you have missing files, try "dotnet publish -c Release" and use the publish folder files (all of them)

Comment: Do you mean run 'dotnet publish -c Release -f netcoreapp1.1' from the roslyn folder and then copy the files from 'artifacts/publish/OmniSharp/default/netcoreapp1.1' to the scripts folder?

Comment: not sure what structure do you have on your project...

Comment: That's the structure of omnisharp-roslyn, but it seems to work that way. If you create an answer from your comment then I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the `System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native` exception happens because you have just copied the compilation folder, that's wrong, you must publish the app and then use the files from that folder, there will be all the libraries the app needs to run.